# php won't upload images? folder is 777

Tags: php, apache, centos, lamp

I have a php script with no erros (I tested it in other servers), the problem is, in this server I cannot upload images from php.

I add 777 to folder and php.ini file upload is on, my image is only 20kb and max file size is 12mb. what else should I check? something in apache? any ideas?

I have this warnings:

```
move_uploaded_file(img-img/14719222_886454304825512_8860750091242176512_n.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/teste.php on line 38, referer: http://example.com/teste2.php
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phptZYSam' to 'img-img/14719222_886454304825512_8860750091242176512_n.jpg' in /var/www/html/teste.php on line 38, referer: http://example.com/teste2.php
```

I already add permission 777 to img-img.

Comment: Check HTTPd access / error logs, check PHP error logs, make sure they're logging appropriate levels. Check if there are any server differences. Are the directories the correct permissions all the way from `/` to your upload dir. If nothing, add some debugging. Test you're entering PHP at all, test you're getting to the upload script, test the $_FILES array is what you expect (assuming you're using forms), is it trying to write files to the place you're expecting. Right now you've told us "something somewhere doesn't work", with absolutely nothing to go by.

Comment: @JonStirling I edited my question with an error that I found.

Comment: Cool. So what does `ls -al /var/www/html/img-img/` give you? Also, have you checked in $_FILES that the upload was successful by checking the `error` key?

Comment: @JonStirling `drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root`

Comment: Well that's not 777 then is it. What user it apache running under? Probably `www-data` or `apache2` or `httpd`. Change the owner to the appropriate user.

Comment: @JonStirling how can I check it? I think it is httpd.

Comment: You could check your system monitor, find the process and that should have a user listed, or depending on your OS, you might be able to find which one exists in `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: As Jon says to find user depends on OS, e. typically on Ubuntu it's www-data - post here lists various means and ways of finding out https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

Comment: @mrjamesmyers mine is centOS. with apache user, what shoud I do next to allow file upload in my img-img folder?

Comment: @mrjamesmyers I have some written in orange as apache and some in the end of the lines /usr/sbin/httpd (httpd in orange)

Comment: If your perms and user are correct, then is the upload path correct.  In the error log it looks like thats a relative path e.g 'img-img/image.png vs '/var/www/html/img-img/image.png'

Comment: @mrjamesmyers I think OP is asking what to run to make the permissions correct. It should be the right dir, the path is relative, but the error shows the script being run.

Comment: I tried: `sudo chown apache /var/www/html/img-img` it execute but no success to upload

Comment: @JonStirling this solve my problem: I don't know what it does, but works... if anyone knows, please, answer this and let me know.

`sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/img-img -R`

Comment: Ah, SELinux can be such a pain. Good work working it out.